# Отсутствует файл lprodump после установки Qt6 и использования LinguistTools в CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt6, qt-linguist

Я столкнулся с проблемой при настройке проекта Qt6 с использованием CMake на Linux Mint.
Несмотря на успешную установку Qt6 и его компонентов, я столкнулся с проблемой, связанной с `Qt6LinguistTools`.
В частности, когда я использую `find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED LinguistTools)` в моем `CMakeLists.txt`, CMake генерирует ошибку, указывающую на отсутствие файла `lprodump`.

Вот сообщение об ошибке, которое я получаю:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6LinguistTools/Qt6LinguistToolsTargets.cmake:131 (message):
  The imported target "Qt6::lprodump" references the file

     "/usr/lib/qt6/libexec/lprodump"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6LinguistTools/Qt6LinguistToolsTargets.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.
```

Я пытался переустановить Qt6 и его компоненты, но файл так и не появился в ожидаемом каталоге.

Существует ли специфический пакет в Linux Mint (Ubuntu), который содержит файл `lprodump` для Qt6, или известен ли какой-либо обходной путь для этой проблемы?

Раньше все работало правильно, и я ничего не менял в системе, что могло бы вызвать эту проблему.

Comment: В убунтовых репозиториях этот файл лежит в пакете `qt6-tools-dev-tools`. Этот пакет у вас доступен?

Comment: @user207200 да, спасибо. Действительно, в этом пакете лежит файл. Очень странно, что у меня возникла такая ошибка. Не помню, чтобы удалял этот пакет.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы решить проблему с отсутствующим файлом `lprodump`, установите пакет `qt6-tools-dev-tools`.

Используйте следующую команду:

```
sudo apt install qt6-tools-dev-tools
```

Это должно решить проблему с отсутствующим файлом.

---

Чтобы проверить, что файл действительно находится в пакете, вы можете использовать утилиту `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -L qt6-tools-dev-tools
```

Вывод:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/qt6
/usr/lib/qt6/bin
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/pixeltool
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/qdbus
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/qdbusviewer
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/qdistancefieldgenerator
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/qtdiag
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/qtdiag6
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/qtplugininfo
/usr/lib/qt6/libexec
/usr/lib/qt6/libexec/lprodump
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/qt6-tools-dev-tools
/usr/share/doc/qt6-tools-dev-tools/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/qt6-tools-dev-tools/copyright
```

Как видно, файл представлен в списке.